# Fast and clever way to get the NON FIRST segment of a C# string

Tags: c#, string, split

I do a `split(' ')` over an string and I want to pull the first element of the returned string in order to get the rest of the string.

f.e. `"THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING".split(' ');`

I want to get all the words but THIS. This is: IS AN AMAZING STRING

The string will always have at least one blank space between the first and the second word because I will put it hard coded

Is there a function that makes this?
thank you

Comment: A bigger question is why are you trying to do this? Do you intend to remove the first word of many strings? What about punctuation, as in "This, is an amazing string."? How about a regex?

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are looking to process String-s or Array-s? I included in my answer also a possibly solution for arrays, not only strings

Comment: No, just 1 string. Well you're right, I could add a "special" character to identify just the first element but I simply choosen doing like this.

Comment: @Knaģis Yes it's a string and there is only one. I mistaken in the title, I'm sorry.

Comment: I'm surprised to learn that C# array's don't have a `tail` method.

Comment: @Bradford: There's [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) that you can call on any enumerable collection (including arrays). The reason arrays don't directly implement a tail method is because they're *arrays*. Their whole purpose is for low-level fast random access. A function like `tail`, turning one immutable sequential-access list into another, doesn't really fit that profile.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try

```
string X = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING";
string Y = (X.IndexOf ( " " ) < 0) ? string.Empty : X.Substring (X.IndexOf ( " " )  + 1); // Y = IS AN AMAZING STRING
```

As per comment (IF `X` is guaranteed to be a valid string with at least one space) a simpler version without checking etc.:

```
string Y = X.Substring (X.IndexOf ( " " )  + 1);
```

Comment: Also consider adding some checks such that it won't break if there is no space in the string.

Comment: The string will always have at least one blank space between the first and the second word because I will put it hard coded.

Comment: @Joel I dont' understand what did you mean to say.

Comment: @Yahia This works. I used your first solution since there is a blank space. X.Substring(X.IndexOf(" ") + 1);

Comment: @senyortoni Intermittent errors come when someone assumes a contract/interface is enforced. You may _always_ put a space in the string, but what happens if you don't? If someone comes behind you and doesn't know that all strings need spaces for this function to work, they'll start seeing errors and have no idea why. Yahia accounts for the case where there is no space in the string by returning 'String.Empty', that way, this code will work even if your string _never_ has a space. That makes for robust SW.

Comment: @JoelB Requirements are requirements. If the source data is not following the contract ***anything*** could be passed in. Anything not following the contract is undefined behavior and should be understood by anyone who uses the API. You are redefining the contract from `Return the text after the first space, all other behavior is undefined` to `Return the text after the first space, if no space return a empty string, all other behavior is undefined`. What if it's null, or the space is the last in the string, or they use Unicode `U+00A0` (Non breaking space). You must draw the line somewhere.

Answer (score 26):

A fairly good option would be to use:

```
string original = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING";
string[] split = original.Split(new []{' '}, 2);
string result = split[1];
```

Note that, if you just want the resulting string, you can shorten this:

```
var result = original.Split(new []{' '}, 2)[1];
```

By using the overload of [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) which takes a max number of splits, you avoid the need to join as well as the extra overhead.

Comment: _Well actually_, the second argument to Split needs to be 2 ;-). Other than that I agree.

Answer (score 17):

```
var a = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING".Split(' ');
string amazing = String.Join(" ", a.Skip(1));
```

If you are on pre-.NET 4, you need to stick a .ToArray() in the end of the Skip call - because the String.Join overload that takes enumerable as the second parameter was first added in .NET 4.

While this works well in the general case, if you always want to remove just the first word, there is a better way of doing this, as pointed out by Reed in comments:

```
var a = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING".Split(new char[] {' ' }, 2);
string amazing = a[1];  //Perhaps do a length check first if you are not sure there is a space in the original string.
```

This performs better for larger strings, since Split only need to look until it finds the first space, and can then create a result with two strings only - and it avoids the String.Join which could also be expensive, especially for longer strings.

Comment: This isn't particularly fast, but it is easy.  It can be improved though by using this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx

Comment: Why -1 ? Note that the question does involve an array in the title, so no way of knowing if the OP actually has the string to split on in the first place.

Comment: And yes, this is not the most performant way of doing it, but it is concise, and for most uses the performance difference will not matter.

Comment: This will be slow for long strings - you first have to split up the string in n places, forming n+1 new strings, then perform n join operations.

Comment: +1 As long as you aren't doing this for a million rows on every request, it's easily readable, easy to maintain and does what you need.

Comment: IMO, it's cleaner to use one of the solutions from Knaģis or Reed.

Comment: @ commenters, thanks for input. I updated the answer to include the Split([],n) overload option. I might have overlooked "Fast" in the question title and might have mis-read "clever" to mean "elegant". FWIW, you can save a bounds check using the first option.

Answer (score 17):

Do NOT use the `Split` function - a) it looks for every `' '` symbol there is, not just the first one. b) this approach will involve lots of copying data around in memory which is rather slow operation for strings.

```
var a = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING";
string result;
var index = a.IndexOf(' ');
if (index == -1)
    result = null;
else
    result = a.Substring(index + 1);
```

Since the title of the question mentions array, not string, it is worth mentioning the [`ArraySegment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cc4bx8k.aspx) class - this enables you to create a pointer to part of the array (without creating a new array and copying data):

```
var a = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
var segment = new ArraySegment<int>(a, 1, a.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Won't compile... (Split returns an array, you probably did not mean that)

Comment: why would I not want to use it?

Comment: @driis - yes, copy-pasted the line and did not notice it

Comment: Explained in the answer why Split should not be used.

Comment: +1. Yes, unless the n-th word has to be skipped, `String.Split` seems not appropriate to me. A good point is the `index == -1` test!

Comment: Either your approach or @Yahia's approach are correct, depending on the requirement of what to do if a space is not found.

Answer (score 2):

Very simply, you could do:

```
string input = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING";
string result = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

This will work for the type of input you're specifying (where there is always a space between the first two words in your string), but for case where the input string does not have spaces at all, it returns the whole string as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  string str = "THIS IS AN AMAZING STRING";
  string firstString = str.Split(' ')[0];  //get the first string
  string newStr = str.Replace(firstString + " ", "");  //remove the first string

  //OR

  string newStr = str.Remove(0, firstString.Length + 1);
```

Comment: has the same issue of Split copying around everything and also Replace will traverse the string for a second time, finding every match.
plus does not work for `THIS THIS THIS IS IS IS AMAAAAZING!`