# Get a UserControl with a certain interface inside a hierarchy

Tags: c#, linq

I have an .aspx page which has many controls.

I want to search recursively the Page.Controls collection.

My own added UserControl has an interface IUserControl.

With this extension method:

```
public static T FindNodeInHierarchy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector, Predicate<T> condition)
        {
            // return default wenn keine Items existieren
            if (source == null || !source.Any()) return default(T);

            // return result wenn item gefunden und hört auf die Liste durchzugehen
            var attempt = source.FirstOrDefault(t => condition(t));
            if (!Equals(attempt, default(T))) return attempt;

            // Ruft die Funktion auf eine Liste auf bis runter in alle Unterlisten bis das
            // entsprechende Objekt gefunden ist.
            return source.SelectMany(childrenSelector).FindNodeInHierarchy(childrenSelector, condition);
        }
```

I get an memory out of exception when I try something like that:

```
 var query = Page.Controls
                .Cast<Control>()
                .FindNodeInHierarchy<Control>(c => Page.Controls.Cast<Control>(), c => c is IUserControl);
```

I did also try `.OfType<IUserControl>()`

but then I get null value returned.

How can I get this UserControl with the IUserControl interface which is put somewhere on

the site?

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<TControl> FindControls<TControl>(Control c)
{
    var tc = c as TControl;
    if (tc != null)
        yield return tc;

    foreach (var cc in c.Controls)
    {
        foreach (var res in FindControls<TControl>(cc))
            yield return res;
    }
}
```

you call this by passing the root control to be searched, for example

```
var myuc = FindControls<IUserControl>(Page);
```

Comment: Thank you but I already have a recursive function. I would like to know how to use it concering finding IUserControl within Page.Controls.

Comment: @Elisa What about this solution doesn't work for you? There is an example usage right there at the bottom.

Comment: I do not want to introduce a new method when I have a generic one. I do want that my code is considered in the solution with my direct context-related problem. And btw. your code does not compile when I put it inside a class. Just try it. Seems your have this copy/paste problem more then once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348519/fast-and-clever-way-to-get-the-non-first-segment-of-a-c-sharp-string/13348572#13348572 :P